# Blender denosing animation render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, denoise

I have rendered an animation in cycles (I accidentally rendered it as mkv instead of an mp4) and I checked denoise before rendering and now that it is rendered it is very very blurry.

I tried to fix this in compositing but I was unable to get the animation to show up on the render layer. Can someone help me with getting rid of the extreme noise in the render.

[image].

Also, I tried to attach the blend file using blend-exchange but it said that there was an internal issue and I do not know how to upload only the animation file.

Comment: You would have to re-render the scene, there is no way getting the original data back so it is advisable to always render an image sequence (ideally OpenEXR) and encode that image sequence afterwards to e.g. mkv or mp4: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec

Comment: what are the settings for an image sequence?